# RoR 3, Passenger, Relative URLs, and helper methods such as root_url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger, mod-rails

I'm really struggling to understand the routing behaviour I'm seeing with a Rails 3 app as it relates to Passenger and routing helper methods.  Here's a quick overview:

When a user registers for my site, one of the things I'd like to do is send out a verification email to make sure the user has submitted a valid email address.  So, I set up mailer to send the user a URL with some sort of magic token, thereby proving that they have received the email I sent.  The URL in the body of the email is generated via a routing helper method (in this case, `verify_url("a1b2c3")` ) and the URL is stuffed into the email appropriately as:

```
http://localhost:3000/verify/a1b2c3
```

This all works great under `localhost:3000` without a hitch.  So, like a responsible developer, the next thing I do is move my app to my remote QA environment and verify that everything still works.  My hosting provider uses Passenger, and I have it set up so that my QA environment can be accessed as follows:

```
http://my.url/qa
```

This is done by setting RailsBaseURI to `/qa` in the appropriate `.htaccess` file.  So, I'm trying to register for the site in my QA environment, and I'm hoping that the helper method `verify_url` generates the following URL:

```
http://my.url/qa/verify/a1b2c3
```

However, this is what I get instead:

```
http://my.url/verify/a1b2c3
```

Notice the distinct lack of reference to the 'qa' path?  I've scoured various blogs and manuals looking for an answer, and I've seen the following suggestions:

- Set an environment variable such as `ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT']`
- Set `ActionController::Base.relative_url_root` in my `environment/qa.rb`
- Add a map to my `config.ru` to initialize my app under a particular path
- Wrap my routes in a scope

However, each of these seems either to be deprecated (the first two options), or ends up producing redundant path info (the second two options) as follows:

```
http://my.url/qa/qa/verify/a1b2c3
```

Can anyone tell me the proper way to set this up, such that when I call `verify_url("a1b2c3")`, I'm actually getting the proper URL, including the relative path for my QA environment?  Ideally, I'd want to be able to set this in `environments/qa.rb` somehow, such that I don't have to change my app at all when moving from one environment to the next.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also, I should add that I'm very new to Rails...  So, if there's something obvious that I'm missing or an alternative way to do this, please do let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would dismiss the whole `/qa/` and move the staging to a subdomain like `http://qa.my.url/` Otherwise you will have to make changes to the code that might affect production in a negative way.

**Update**

I've ignored the the fact that you wanted to use those routes in emails. In this case you will have to set `:host` in the url helper:

```
verify_url(:id=>"a1b2c3", :host=>"qa.my.url")
```

To cut down the amount of changes you would have to make once you go into production, I would suggest you define a constant in an initializer (in `/path/to/app/config/initializers/my_host.rb`):

```
MY_HOST = 'qa.my.url'
```

After that you could call `verify_url` in your email templates like so:

```
verify_url(:id=>"a1b2c3", :host=>MY_HOST)
```

Once you go into production, change the `MY_HOST` constant and you won't have to worry about the templates.

In my views I never use the `*_url` helpers, only the `*_path` ones to circumvent this issue.

Comment: Actually, I should have mentioned this, but my original intent was to use a subdomain.  However, I went away from this approach early on, as I experienced the same problem.  When running under a subdomain such as `qa`, using a routing helper like `verify_url` still produces `http://my.url/verify/a1b2c3` rather than the desired `http://qa.my.url/verify/a1b2c3`.  Is there some way to let Rails' helper methods know that its running under a subdomain?

Comment: Ah, I see.  Simple and elegant.  I had hand-crafted something similar without using the `*_url` helpers, but it didn't quite feel like the "rails way".  This feels better.  Besides, now that I think about it, the only time I'll ever really need the `*_url` helpers (as opposed to the `*_path` helpers) is in mailers, so this will work very well for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After spending a little time with the ActionMailer docs, it turns out that there is an even easier solution, at least for what I am looking to accomplish.  Wukerplank definitely answered my question, but it seems that I wasn't quite asking the right question. :-)

The only time I really need to see the fully qualified URL is when I'm working within a mailer, right?  Otherwise, paths work just fine.  Well, it turns out that ActionMailer allows you to specify default url options on a per-environment basis.  In my `environments/development.rb` config file, I now have the following:

`config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }`

When I move to my QA environment, I just need to tell Passenger that I'm running from QA, and have something like this `environments/qa.rb` config:

`config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'qa.my.url' }`

That way, the code doesn't have to change one bit between environments, and thus, I really don't care what domain, subdomain, or port I'm running on...  It just works.  Hope this helps someone else in the future.  Thanks!